# Why is this the cause of the dread brewing in my stomach?

Tags: riddle, enigmatic-puzzle

#### What do they have in common?

It’s the beginning of a new future. Discard trivialities and you’ll reach what’s perpetually yet to come.

> Tomato and the mouse’s nemesis
> Nor is it a connective option that
> Crows go gently down the stream.

#### Another treat

> Silencing pastry marks the beginning. (5)

#### The universally feared

> Test and quiz
> I'm me.
> Countries and republics.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The first part was solved by [hagfy](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/66106/43477), and the second by [Ian MacDonald](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/66102/43477). The third part is...

> Test and quiz = EXAM
>  I'm me = I
>  Countries and republics = NATIONS

Which leads me to believe that the answer is...

> EXAMINATIONS START TOMORROW

That can certainly be dreadful, but good luck!

Comment: Not quite. The answer is the other way around.

Comment: @SohaFarhinPine: Ah yes, it sounds better that way.

Comment: @SohaFarhinPine: The third part wasn't bad. It took the longest to solve after all, so it must have been more challenging. ;) Overall, a nice mix of different puzzle types.

Answer (score 11):

I'm not sure how this fits, so I'm going to go ahead and tag #partialanswer here.

> Silencing pastry marks the beginning. (5)

Could be:

> Start
>  "Tart" is a pastry and the universal "be quiet" sound uttered by librarians the English-speaking-world-over ("shh") might be compressed as "s". With "start" obviously marking "the beginning".

Comment: It is, indeed! +1

Answer (score 11):

Partial answer (first part) -

--Edited in an attempt to further clarify my thought process--

> Each line has two parts: a word and a clue.  We're grabbing the common characters between the two

Tomato and the mouse’s nemesis

> **Tomato**
> "the mouses's nemesis" - Jerry (the antagonistic mouse) considers **Tom** (the cat) his nemesis
>
> The shared characters are **TOM**

Nor is it a connective option that

> **Nor**
> "a connective option" - **or** is a conjunction that has common letters with 'Nor'
>
> The shared characters are **OR**

Crows go gently down the stream.

> **Crows**
> "gently down the stream" - I think of **row**, row, rowing a boat
>
> The shared characters are **ROW**

Answer:

> Put them all together and you get **TOMORROW**
> Tomorrow is the next day and therefore begins the future
> 'Tomorrow' never actually comes, it is always 'Today'

Comment: Kudos! This was the main part and I hope the most fun one too!

Comment: @SohaFarhinPine I can't say whether I enjoyed it more than the ones who solved the other parts, but it was definitely more fun than taking a test!  =D   I thought it was very clever, and I like the variety in the types of clues. Thank you for the puzzle, and best of luck to you!

Comment: Aww...thanks! I never have put much effort into making my puzzles, but surprisingly they always do manage to get a decent reception at the least.

Comment: Could you check out this question of mine: https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/35121/what-are-the-limits-to-description-in-story-writing-how-should-i-know-if-i-have/36117#36117. It's on Writing SE.

Comment: Okay how did you get the "and or" from the "connecting option that"?

Comment: @SohaFarhinPine Sorry, I may be quite pedantic at times, but prose is as foreign to me as, well...something really foreign.  In other words, I don't English good.

Comment: @hagfy Oh, no. I wasn't talking about you or anyone else specifically for that matter. I just meant that the community as a whole just has relatively higher standards than the rest of SE.

Comment: @htmlcoderexe I edited my answer to elaborate somewhat...maybe it makes more sense now?

Comment: @SohaFarhinPine Understood, just wanted to keep expectations of me low.  =D

Comment: Wow...the edit is impressive. Only wish I could upvote you more!